# R - Delete columns based on the value of a specific row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table which contains a "Total" row that sums all previous rows for each column. I'd like to delete every column that has a total inferior to 10. In the following example, that would mean deleting column B and C.

| ID | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 1 | 2 | 10 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 3 | 15 |
| C | 7 | 1 | 1 | 22 |
| Total | 12 | 2 | 6 | 47 |

I haven't really tried anything because I am not familiar at all dealing with specific rows in R. Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You could `select` the columns `where` the `last` value is higher than 10 like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(where(~ last(.x) > 10))
#>      ID  A  D
#> 1     A  5 10
#> 2     B  0 15
#> 3     C  7 22
#> 4 Total 12 47
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Data used:

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID A   B   C   D
A   5   1   2   10
B   0   0   3   15
C   7   1   1   22
Total   12  2   6   47
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Works because `"Total" > "10"` but would fail silently if it was (for example) `_Total`.

Comment: This solution makes assumptions about the row order, which might be dangerous and silently fail, as @s_baldur noted.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
Filter(\(x) !is.numeric(x) || x[length(x)] >= 10, df)

#      ID  A  D
# 1     A  5 10
# 2     B  0 15
# 3     C  7 22
# 4 Total 12 47
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "B", "C", "Total"), 
  A = c(5L, 0L,  7L, 12L), 
  B = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 2L), 
  C = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 6L), 
  D = c(10L, 15L, 22L, 47L)
)
```